# What is the best way to bypass my squid proxy via squid configuration - for managing network devices and firewalls, etc via https?

Tags: proxy

The issue is that right now, engineers, etc., must modify Internet Explorer and add each address into the exceptions individually.

We have a very large environment so this is very tedious and everyone has to do it on their own browser. If there was a way to configure the proxy to bypass itself for specific subnets or forward traffic to the destination, that would be ideal.

I would imagine there has to be a way to do this, but can't seem to find it in the documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have everyone configure their proxy using a Proxy-Auth-Config (PAC) file, in your pac file setup exceptions by destination.  Host the packfile on a web server somewhere, and have all your IT staff point at the same pac.  That way, if you need to add more exceptions, you just modify the file.

Keeping in mind that most browsers do cache the file for a bit, so changes on the web server will not immediately be reflected on all the clients.  You may also want to set proper cache-control headers so that caching is minimized.

You could also work on fixing your squid to actually work properly with internal resources. Without knowing the specifics of how/where it is deployed and where the internal resources are, or the kinds of errors you are getting, when you try to access internal resources with the proxy in place, it is hard to know what you would need to do to fix that.

Comment: thx, I have 2 interfaces on squid. The EXT which leads to the internet and the INT, which leads to all internal resources (RFC 1918 addresses). Internal subnets are defined in the squid.conf file ACL as local_net src (defined as subnets, maybe i need to format differently?). When I try to reach a local resource https://192.168.10.25 with proxy configured in IE, I receive error: "The page cannot be displayed *Make sure the web address is correct". Seems the proxy is taking all requests whether local addresses or internet addresses and trying to forward them out the external interface.

Comment: Squid.conf ACL example: acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network

Comment: acl to_localnet dst 10.0.0.0/8

Comment: Still learning how to use formatting on this site, apologies. In my first comment, I need to clarify that I am using the browser to reach internal resources over https + IP address. The way you would browse to a web interface of a home router, etc